# Not able to Ping to MacBooks?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, network

Recently while troubleshooting some network issues, we figured out we are not able to ping any of our 85+ MacBook Pros. On further analysis we checked and confirmed firewall is not enabled on any of the machines.

Is there something very basic we're missing?

Comment: Can you otherwise access the machines (e.g. SSH/AFP, etc..)? If so, it sounds like something is swallowing ICMP_ECHO requests.

Answer (score 2):

Check **System Preferences** → **Security** → **Firewall** → **Firewall Options…** → **Enable Stealth Mode** is not ticked.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with Wireless access point. We had enabled the wireless isolation which has caused the problem.

Comment: Moving OP's 2011 comment providing answer to a real answer.